# Integrating custom membership provider in existing solution

Tags: asp.net, membership, provider, solution

I have the source for the sqlMembershipProvider and the sqlRolesProvider that MS ships and I want to modify it to use my own tables and schema.

I have an existing solution that will use this provider and I'd like to debug the provider code within that solution until I'm sure it works.

How do I set up my provider code in a project within that solution so I can reference my custom provider in the solution's web project's web.config?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter as long as you provide a fully qualified type name in the config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="YourProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="YourProvider" type="FullTypeName, YourAssembly"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

It can be a type in a separate assembly, or in a web application. It won't work in case of a "Web Site" project though, because all code in App_Code folder is compiled on the fly, so you can't tell its type name.